# App Suddenly Exits When Tried to Call given number

Tags: java, android, android-intent, phone-call

I Tried to Create Caller app using intent, in android studio ide code is error free but when it is run on live device & put in the number in EditText & Call button is pressed app suddenly exits.. im unable to find what causes this app behaviour and why call is not getting placed..How do i make it work ?

```
MainActivity.java

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 EditText txt_phn;
 Button btn_call;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_phn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_phn);
        btn_call=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
        btn_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                mck();
            }
        });


    }
    private void mck()
    {


        
        String number = "tel:" + txt_phn.getText().toString().trim();

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number));

        try {
            startActivity(callIntent);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished making a call", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
Manifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.caller">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_phn"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Please Enter Phone Number To Call"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="360dp"
        android:text="Call"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
2020-08-10 20:04:47.337 23806-23806/com.example.caller E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.caller, PID: 23806
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity } from ProcessRecord{70113a3 23806:com.example.caller/u0a425} (pid=23806, uid=10425) with revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3851)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1714)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5210)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5168)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5539)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5507)
        at com.example.caller.MainActivity.mck(MainActivity.java:49)
        at com.example.caller.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:19)
        at com.example.caller.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7260)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7237)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:802)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27915)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:915)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1058)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:762)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:585)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1298)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:516)
```

Comment: If the app "suddenly exits", that means that it crashed. If it crashes, there will be exception logs and stack trace in the logcat. Please look there. If you can't figure it out, post the relevant parts of the logcat here in your question.

Comment: okay..i will post logcat shortly..

Comment: it seems you need to get the permission for android.permission.CALL_PHONE. add it and will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i got the fix for it..thanks to "David Wasser" as i didnt looked at logcat initially. through his suggetion i looked at logcat & found an error of runtime call permission which i didn't added in code , and this hint also given by "vikas kumar" thanks to him..
now the changes. following are the changes i made in mainactivity : -

```
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startActivity(callIntent);
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{CALL_PHONE}, 1);
        }
```

this asks for runtime permission for telephony & when granted it will directly place a call.

```
Why This changes needed ?
Because from Android 6.0 Above there were api changes & also permission related changes.
& i followed older example of calling app tutorial.
```